# Unity Fails to Build to Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm getting this error in unity 2018 when trying to build to Android

**CommandInvokationFailure**: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
exit code: -1073741819
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Answer (score 0):

What does the project contain? Did you download any packages in addition to the basic Unity stuff?

Also - Did you install the Android SDK and JDK?

Comment: No there are no external packages, it didn't even build on a blank project